# flutter Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer

Tags: flutter, dart

Whenever I try to run my code this error pops up:

```
> Could not get unknown property 'release' for SigningConfig container of type org.gradle.api.internal.FactoryNamedDomainObjectContainer.
```

I have try to use this

```
 signingConfigs {
        release {
            keyAlias keystoreProperties['keyAlias']
            keyPassword keystoreProperties['keyPassword']
            storeFile file(keystoreProperties['storeFile'])
            storePassword keystoreProperties['storePassword']
        }
    }
```

still, yet I cant run my code......

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

try adding this in your app/build.gradle at the top of android {...}

```
def keystoreProperties = new Properties()
def keystorePropertiesFile = rootProject.file('key.properties')
if (keystorePropertiesFile.exists()) {
    keystoreProperties.load(new FileInputStream(keystorePropertiesFile))
}
```

Then after generate .jsk file following tutorial

https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-sign-and-release-your-flutter-app-ed5e9531c2ac

Answer (score -1):

Add in variants

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
```

Do not add in

```
defaultConfig {
  .
  .
  signingConfig signingConfigs.release
}
```